# communicating between two dataSources on same XPage

Tags: datasource, xpages

I have an XPage that is not bound to a dataSource. The XPage contains two Custom Controls that are each bound to a different dataSource say mainDoc and transDoc. From an action button in transDoc I need to get a handle to the dataSource of the main custom control and the dataSource "mainDoc". This Action button needs to  perform a save on mainDoc, plus some other stuff. I have some logic that 'hides' the mainDoc custom control and displays the transDoc control. The user then fills in some info in the transDoc Control and clicks an action that needs to then save the mainDoc first then save the transDoc. The sequence of the saves is crucial. Under some conditions we might hide the transDoc control and un-hide the mainDoc control without saving, I have that part working because I do not need to get the dataSource handle to do that.

I seem to vaguely remember reading something like this somewhere but can't seem to find it now.

Comment: Here is a way to access a datasource: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to access the data source from another custom control is using a **scope variable**.

Set in first custom control a view scope variable to data source `mainDoc` in `beforePageLoad` event:

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.sourceMainDoc = mainDoc}]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

Then you can work in second custom control with this view scope and e.g. save the `mainDoc`:

```
<xp:this.action>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.sourceMainDoc.save()}]]>
</xp:this.action>
```

*Alternative*

Use [Sven Hasselbach's](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=777) way to get data source from custom control. You'll get an object of instance `com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData`. If you want to use same methods like for normal data source Domino Document objects (= NotesXspDocument) you have to get an object of instance `com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument` with `getDataObject()` first. You can do it this way:

```
function getDatasource( componentId:String, dataSourceName:String ):com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData {
    ...
}
var mainDoc:com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument = getDatasource("idDSComponent", "mainDoc").getDataObject();
mainDoc.save()
```

Comment: There is a small difference between the datasource and the backend document: If you access the wrapped document you just access the backend notes document. But when saving the datasource, all defined actions (f.e. *querySave* and *postSave*) are executed.

Comment: @Sven: I see, if I want to execute data sources' events (_querySaveDocument_ and _postSaveDocument_) while saving I have to use DominoDocumentData instead of wrapped DominoDocument. This is always the case not only when accessing data source from another custom control. How to call save() for DominoDocumentData you described here: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=save-datasource-fire-querysavepostsave-events. - In case I don't have events defined the save() for wrapped DominoDocument would work too.

Comment: I like the getDatasource process and think that might be the best way to go to work with the actual DataSource rather than the backend document. In Sven's example he added the id="dataSource" into the source code so it would look like <xc:ccMain id="idMainDataSource"></xc:ccMain> In the All Properties of the Custom Control I set the id = "idMainDataSource". Is this functionally the same as editing the source?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. If you set the id in All Properties then you should see it in source code too.

Comment: After working a bit with the process I have settled on using the viewScope process rather than the getDataSource function. I need access to the dataSource many time on a single page and I would guess that the viewScource.get would be somewhat more efficeint than calling getDataSource 20 or 30 times.